# Save resulting JSON into SQLite - Django

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
def getExchangeRates():
    """ Here we have the function that will retrieve the latest rates from fixer.io """
    rates = []
    response = urlopen('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=c2f5070ad78b0748111281f6475c0bdd')
    data = response.read()
    rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float) 
    rates_from_rdata = rdata.get('rates', {})
    for rate_symbol in ['USD', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'JPY', 'SEK', 'NOK']:
        try:
            rates.append(rates_from_rdata[rate_symbol])
        except KeyError:
            logging.warning('rate for {} not found in rdata'.format(rate_symbol)) 
            pass

    return rates

@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def index(request):
    rates = getExchangeRates()   
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

The resulting `json` from `data.fixer.io` has a format, like, `currency | rate_of_the_currency`.

Something like this: `"rates": {"SAR": 4.394498, "INR": 49.836962, and so on...`, so, I have created this model on Django:

```
class Fixerio_rates(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    rate = models.FloatField()
```

Now, how can I save the result from my code into this model? migrations have been made already, it shouldn't be something complex to do, but since this is a migration from `Flask` into `Django` it confuses me a bit. It's kind of a different approach, Django has it's own way to deal with these things.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) queryset method, which adds multiple records in one database query (the efficient way). So your code should look like this:

First rewrite your function getExchangeRates so you get one dict for all currencies instead of list of dicts for each currency

```
rates = {}
...
for rate_symbol in ['USD', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'JPY', 'SEK', 'NOK']:
    try:
        rates[rate_symbol] = rates_from_rdata[rate_symbol]
    except KeyError:
        logging.warning('rate for {} not found in rdata'.format(rate_symbol)) 
        pass

return rates
```

Then iterate over dict creating model instances and save them bulk after that.

```
rates = getExchangeRates()
fixerio_rates = [Fixerio_rates(currency=currency, rate=rate)
                 for currency, rate in rates.items()]
Fixerio_rates.objects.bulk_create(fixerio_rates)
```